# How to set NBSP shortcut in Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I change the keyboard combination for a non-breaking space (NBSP) from `shift`+`space` to something else?

It took a while for me to figure this out: when coding, I run into issues related to using an NBSP accidentally, for example at `… = "…`. Python for example complains about `invalid character in identifier` here. That is because I leave `Shift` pressed while typing all the characters, which makes the spaces be NBSPs.

This happens only on my computer running Manjaro Gnome, in any application (Firefox, Evolution, gedit, Atom, LibreOffice, …). On my other computer running OSX the combination of `Shift`+`Space` does not change the regular space character.

According to [the NBSP WP entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) this is not even the default key combination to generate an NBSP, but I can not remember me changing this anywhere.

So this is why I am asking where this setting could be placed, or how I can change this in Manjaro Gnome 17.1 Hakoila?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting [Ignacio](https://superuser.com/a/1275350/154140) talks about is actually placed in [Gnome Tweaks](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Tweaks) at `Keyboard and Mouse` -> `Additional Layout Options` > `Using space key to input non-breaking space`. I set it to 3rd level and hope I will never hit this by accident.

Answer (score 2):

In the "Keyboard" control panel, "Layout" tab, "Options..." button, there is an entry for "Using space key to input non-breaking space". <kbd>Shift</kbd> is the second level, there is a separate option to assign the third level, and fourth level is second+third level.